# How to return qrcode to dataurl encoding for json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a nodejs function to encoding qrcode and want return result back to caller function, to create json response. But I don't know why it can't return data response. What's wrong with my code. Can you help me please.

```
gen_qrcode : function () {
    var QRCode = require('qrcode');
    var qr_url = "https://www.google.com";
    var qr_data = QRCode.toDataURL(qr_url, { errorCorrectionLevel: 'M' }, function (err, url) {
        console.log(url);
    });
    return qr_data;
}
```

json response that I want to create

```
{
"status": 1,
"description": "Success",
"qr_data": "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"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer that shows how to make a JSON string. Let me know if you have a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QRCode.toDataURL` uses callback function (which once it asynchronously retrieves the url, it calls the callback function with the parameters, therefore you can not directly return this.)

However, if you do not specify a callback it returns a Promise. You can return the Promise, and use the `then` method on the Promise to get the value.

```
gen_qrcode : function() {
    var QRCode = require('qrcode');
    var qr_url = "https://www.google.com";
    return QRCode.toDataURL(qr_url, { errorCorrectionLevel: 'M' });
}

//other function
object_name.gen_qrcode().then((url) => {
    let json_object = JSON.stringify({
       status: 1,
       description: 'Success',
       qr_data: url 
    })
    console.log(json_object); //do something with json_object
})
```

Alternatively, you can use Async/Await ([browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions)) with instructions [here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode#es6es7)

Comment: Thank you for help full, Steve Tang. From your suggestion it's work now.